# Tomar la altura máxima de un DIV padre para aplicar CSS overflow

Tags: css3

Tengo un modal, dividido en 2 columnas, la primera columna almacena información de un registro y la segunda un historial de cambios. El historial se llena hacia abajo con cada movimiento que se hace a la información. El problema es que llega un momento que son tantos comentarios que ya no caben en el div, así que apliqué un estilo para poder ver más abajo

```
.more-data-vertical{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Sin embargo no me lo está tomando en cuenta al parecer por que no tiene un `max-height`, no le puedo poner uno fijo por que varía dependiendo del tamaño que tenga la información.

Agrego un fragmento de código, verlo en pantalla completa de favor.

```css
.comentario{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  border: 1px solid #7dd4cf;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.more-data-vertical{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 data">
              <form action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 coms more-data-vertical">
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo establecer el `max-height` de mi DIV de comentarios que sea el `height` de mi DIV de información?

Intenté

```
.more-data-vertical{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

**No Javascript**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y si le das un maximo de alto a la columna de la izquierda, pero relativo al viewport algo así:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .more-data-vertical {
    max-height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```css
.comentario{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  border: 1px solid #7dd4cf;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.more-data-vertical{
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
  .more-data-vertical {
    max-height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 data">
              <form action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 coms more-data-vertical">
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
              <div class="comentario">COMENTARIO 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```